# Overlay Displaying Before Button Is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I have a Web Page that contains a button which toggles the function `toggleOverlay` which displays an overlay, as well as can close the overlay. The overlay is a div. Inside the div, I have nested an `iFrame` which references another local html file I have and displays it. However, the only way I could make it so that the iFrame would display the local html file was if in the CSS I took out the attribute `display:none`. But the function depends on that attribute to determine wether the overlay is displayed or not. How can I get around this, because as of currently the overlay div is displayed when the page is first loaded.

**Currently**

- The Overlay is Displayed when the page first loads
- `display:none` has been taken out of the css to allow the iFrame to actually display the local html file

**Goals**

- Make it so that the iframe continues to be able to display the local html file
- modify the function so that the overlay does not show up when the page is first loaded but rather when the button is pressed.

**HTML**

```
<div id="specialBox">
  <iframe src="SlideOne.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close Overlay</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#specialBox {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    overlay.style.opacity = .8;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you have `display: none`? Was it on `div#specialBox`? And where is the HTML element with ID "overlay"?

Comment: @NicklasNygren The `display: none` was in `div#specialBox`. The HTML element with ID `overlay` is in the same file as the div `special box`.